# SourceTree: How to show Merge Conflicts alert?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

**Context**

I'm using the latest version of Atlassian SourceTree for Windows, 2.1.2.5, with Git.

By default in SourceTree, a Git merge operation that results in a merge conflict pops up an alert dialog like this:

[image: SourceTree Merge Conflicts alert]

**Problem/Question**

If you check the box for "Don't ask me again", how do you later re-enable these Merge Conflict alerts?

**What I've Tried**

- SourceTree's settings GUI, in the *Tools* menu > *Options*.
- SourceTree's config file: `%LocalAppData%\SourceTree\app-2.1.2.5\SourceTree.exe.config`, for which I did a before-and-after Diff: No changes.
- Any other config/ini/xml/json/etc files in `%LocalAppData%\SourceTree\app-2.1.2.5\` or subfolders (log4net had some)
- Anything in `%LocalAppData%\SourceTree-Settings`. Only an empty log file there.
- The Registry. Doesn't look like Atlassian stores settings under HKLM/Software or HKCU/Software, and a search for "MergeConflict" turned up nothing relevant.

Answer (score 5):

On a Mac...

...if you installed manually, run:

```
defaults write com.torusknot.SourceTreeNotMAS suppressConflictsWarning 0
```

...if you installed via AppStore, run:

```
defaults write com.torusknot.SourceTree suppressConflictsWarning 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Found it! Although the SourceTree.exe is in `%LocalAppData%\SourceTree\app-2.1.2.5\`, the config file it uses is`%LocalAppData%\Atlassian\SourceTree.exe_Url_st3ep4nxaste3ioklih3k2gbvcxfuqlh\2.1.2.5\user.config`

Obviously.

Inside that XML file is a node like

```
<setting name="SuppressConflictsWarning" serializeAs="String">
    <value>True</value>
</setting>
```

Exit SourceTree, change the above `True` to `False`, save it and restart SourceTree.

If you've had several versions of SourceTree on your PC, you may have several gibberish-named folders inside `%LocalAppData%\Atlassian\`. Each one contains a single folder, which is named for a SourceTree version (one had a `2.1.2.4` folder, another had a `2.1.2.5` folder, etc.). In my case, 2.1.2.5 was the latest version, so I edited the `user.config` in that one and it worked.

Comment: For the latest version (3.0.12) of SourceTree the setting is under `%LocalAppData%\SourceTree\app-3.0.12\SourceTree.exe.config` file